# java - Interface with comapreTo that child classes override using themselves

Tags: java, interface, parent-child, compareto

I have an interface that I want to have a compareTo that is overridden by the children to use the child as its basis of comparison. For example:

Parent:

```
public interface Parent extends Comparable<Parent> {
    @Override
    int compareTo(Parent o);
}
```

Child:

```
public class Child implements Parent {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Child o) {
        //  do things
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Parent a = new Child();
Parent b = new Child();
a.compareTo(b); // uses the child compareTo
```

Something like the above is what I'd like to accomplish. As it is, the Child doesn't think there is anything to override. What needs to change? Thanks.

Comment: `public int compareTo(Child o)` isn't part of `Parent` so of course there is nothing to override...

Comment: Maybe you should tell us why you need to do this? So that we can give you an alternative solution.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make Child implement both Comparable and Parent?

Answer (score 0):

Such thing is not achievable in Java.

In Parent, you have

```
int compareTo(Parent o)
```

and in Child, you have

```
int compareTo(Child o)
```

Given that they accept different parameter, they are overloaded methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Child implements Comparable, Parent{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        System.out.println("works");
        return 0;
    }
}
public interface Parent {
    public int compareTo(Object o);
}
 Parent parent1= new Child();
        Parent parent2= new Child();
        parent1.compareTo(parent2);
```

Prints--- works
Not sure if you are looking for this in particular.